# return relationship rather than just n

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following cypher query, which returns the nodes I want. However, I want to get not just the node, but also the relationship and nodes it connects to (i.e. i'd like the result to have the format (i:Importer)-[r:Customer]->(c:Contractor). Im not sure, but I suspect I need an additional match function that feeds in 'c' if that makes sense?

Many thanks!

```
MATCH (i:Importer)-[r:Customer]->(c:Contractor)
with c,  count (distinct r) as partners
where partners > 20
return c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to include another `MATCH` as you said.

```
MATCH (i:Importer)-[r:Customer]->(c:Contractor)
with count (r) as partners, c 
where partners > 20
MATCH (i:Importer)-[r:Customer]->(c:Contractor)
return c, r, i
```

This will give you all `(i:Importer)-[r:Customer]->(c:Contractor)` where `c` has more than 20 `r`s.

Comment: Is it working for you?